# How to return NaN or empty matrix if a condition is false

Tags: matlab

I have a question based on the below function. How to return a NaN or empty matrix if a condition is false.

Below function actually check if the Anchor ID and Source ID are present and if such a combination exists it goes further inside the loop to check if Anchor Channel and Source Channel exists if it exists then it will calculate "y" and goes on. But what if the Anchor Channel and source Channel does not exist for this condition ? and also consider what if Anchor ID and source ID does not exist !!! If it does not exist then I want it to return to NaN or simply nil.

How to modify this function to my requirements ??

```
function [rssi_dBm1]= sampletrue(BlinkSetList,AnchorID,SourceID)

for i=1:length(BlinkSetList)
    S=cell2mat(BlinkSetList(i));                                   
    for j=1:length(S)
        if S(j).AnchorID==AnchorID && S(j).SourceID==SourceID       
            if S(j).AnchorChan==0 && S(j).SourceChan==0             
                y=S(j).agc;                                             
                rssi_dB1(i)= -(33+y*(89-33)/(29-1));
            else
                rssi_dB1(i)=NaN;              
            end
        end
    end
end

rssi_dB1(rssi_dB1==0)=[];
rssi_dBm1=sum(rssi_dB1(:))/length(rssi_dB1);
disp([sprintf('The rssi value  with A-Chan 0 and S-Chan 0 is %0.0f',rssi_dBm1)]);
```

Note: This is just a one part of the conditions, there are still three more combinations for anchor channel and source channel to evaluate.

If the question is still not clear post your doubts and I will try to explain it more precisely.

Your help is highly appreciated . Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the function declaration line (`function...` statement)?

Comment: @Shai Just have a look at the edited version.maybe now it makes sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example of function returning Nan

```
function ret = retNan( value )
if value == true
   ret = 1;
else
   ret = NaN;  % set returned value to Nan
end
```

A function that returns an empty matrix

```
function ret = retEmpty( value )
if value == true
   ret = 1;
else
   ret = [];  % set returned value to an empty matrix
end
```

**EDIT:**
Bottom line, whatever the value of variable `ret`  (or in your case, `rssi_dBm1`) is at the end of the function - this value is returned. So, if `ret` is empty or `NaN` the function simply returns an empty/`NaN` value.
You may set `rssi_dBm1` to be an empty matrix at the beginning of the function and only change it if conditions are satisfied. In that case if all conditions fails the function will return the default value - an empty matrix.

PS,
1. It is best [not to use `i` and `j` as variable names in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab).
2. You can use `mean` instead of `sum()/length()`.
3. instead of `disp( sprintf(...) )` you may use `fprintf(1, ... )`

Comment: Not that it affects the answer but surely just `if value` ? Why the `== true`?

Comment: @Dan - I wanted to make clear the meaning of `value`. It is for presentation only.

Comment: @Shai 4) instead of `fprintf(1, ...)` you can use just `fprintf(...)` :)

Comment: @EitanT - I like to make things **really** explicit (see Dan's comment as well).

Comment: @Shai Do you think you can show in the above code I have pasted ? I tried and funny thing is everything is giving me "NaN" which is not correct

Comment: @Shai I have edited it again and see where I have included the NaN